# Validar Token con JWT C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tokens

Tengo un clase que genera un token de sesión el cual se genera correctamente y puede ser usado, pero no encontrado la manera de validar, el tiempo de vida del token y el mismo token, estoy usando la libreria `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;` para hacer el token:

Mi Clase:

```
public class AuthHelper
{
    public string Auth(tbl_personaModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            var tokenString = "";
            if (model.Identificacion != 0 && model.Clave != null)
            {
                var tokenHandler = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

                var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                {
                    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                    {
                    new Claim( "Correo", model.Identificacion.ToString()),
                    new Claim( "Clave", model.Clave )
                    }),
                    Expires = now.AddMinutes(3),
                    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("secretKeyUser202002172120")), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256),
                };
                IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true; //To show detail of error and see the problem
                var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

                tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
                if (tokenString == null)
                {
                    tokenString = "";
                }
            }

            return tokenString;
        }
        catch (Exception )
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
    }
}
```

En mi controlador solo estoy valorando que el token no llegue vacío, pero no valoro que el token corresponda a el usuario y tampoco el tiempo de vida de dicho token, he intentado utilizando una condicional con el parámetro `Expires` pero no ha funcionado, como podria hacerlo?

Comment: Estás utilizando ASP.NET Core o Framework ?

Comment: Estoy usando Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para validar el Token JWT, puedes hacerlo mediante el método **`ValidateToken()`** de la clase `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler`.

Un ejemplo sería el siguiente:

```
            SecurityToken securityToken;
            var tokenHandler = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidAudience = audienceToken,
                ValidIssuer = issuerToken,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                // DELEGADO PERSONALIZADO PERA COMPROBAR
                // LA CADUCIDAD EL TOKEN.
                LifetimeValidator = this.LifetimeValidator,
                IssuerSigningKey = securityKey
            };

            // COMPRUEBA LA VALIDEZ DEL TOKEN
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, 
                                                                 validationParameters, 
                                                                 out securityToken);
            HttpContext.Current.User = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, 
                                                                  validationParameters, 
                                                                  out securityToken);
```

Como puedes ver la validación del tiempo de vida (LifeTime) se realiza en los parámetros de la clase `TokenValidationParameters()` en la propiedad `LifetimeValidator` mediante un delegado personalizado:

```
   // COMPRUEBA LA CADUCIDAD DEL TOKEN
    public bool LifetimeValidator(DateTime? notBefore, 
                                  DateTime? expires, 
                                  SecurityToken securityToken, 
                                  TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
    {
        var valid = false;

        if ((expires.HasValue && DateTime.UtcNow < expires)
            && (notBefore.HasValue && DateTime.UtcNow > notBefore))
        { valid = true; }

        return valid;
    }
```

Para una información mas completa te recomiendo leas con detenimiento este artículo:
[JSON Web Token - Seguridad en servicios Web API 2 de ASP.NET](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2019/6/17/json-web-token-seguridad-en-servicios-web-api-2-de-aspnet)